# Is NSTextView missing an insert link functionality?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I created an OS X text editor application (with swift) that uses an NSTextView.
When you right click a link in NSTextView you can choose edit and then a panel pops up and enables you to edit the link.

[image: It looks like this]

Is there a way to on insert a link in the same way?

I know NSTextView recognizes links automatically but that does not provide the functionality I need. I need the ability to insert link text and link url that are different from one another.

I currently implemented this by letting the user select text and showing a popup (after pressing cmd+K) where he can enter the link. Then I add the link by:

```
textStorage?.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: url, range: range)
```

This works, but it seems really strange that apple won't implement this kind of basic behavior in an important control as NSTextView.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Type the url and when it is recognized as a link, edit the text. Or add a menu item "Link" and connect it to the first responder and `orderFrontLinkPanel:`.

Comment: Thanks @Willeke. This solution works great!